# IntelliJ does not recognize PATH variable

Tags: java, shell, path, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I recently tried to import an existing Gradle project, using the option "Open Project" in the startup window and the existing build.gradle file to automatically set-up the project.

Right after I did this, an error message appeared in IntelliJ, saying:

> Could not fetch model of type 'BasicIdeaProject' using Gradle installation '/Users/myUser/Tools/gradle-1.3'.
>   Build file '/Users/myUser/IdeaProjects/myProject/database/build.gradle' line: 20
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':database'.
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':database'.
>   'play' command was not found in PATH.
>   Make sure you have Play Framework 2.0 installed and in your path

As it looks like, IntelliJ complains that I did not add the play framework to my PATH variable. Although output from the shell tells sth. else:

```
echo $PATH; 
/usr/local/bin:/Users/myUser/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/myUser/.yadr/bin:/Users/myUser/.yadr/bin/yadr:/Users/myUser/Tools/gradle/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.2.2-x86_64//bin:/Users/myUser/Tools/groovy/bin:/Users/myUser/Tools/play-2.0
```

I also wrote a simple class to display the PATH variable used by IntelliJ:

```
public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( System.getenv( "PATH" ));
    }
}
```

When I run this class, it gives me following output:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As it looks like, IntelliJ completely ignore the PATH variable set in the shell. So I'd like to know how to manipulate/configure IntelliJ to recognise this PATH variable?

The shell I am using is zsh.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this post: https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/ The problem is that IDEA doesn't read your `.zshrc` file and doesn't know about path to play. Try to set PATH variable manually in IDEA settings.

Answer (score 16):

You can actually use "open -a [IntelliJ App]" on mac from the command line and it should pick up your path variables for your .bash_profile and/or .zshrc - better than cutting and pasting into IntelliJ IMO.  Seems to be a mac only issue if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: getting error: The file /Applications/App] does not exist. Am I doing something wrong?