# Setup git in Intellij terminal

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea

I want to use git in Intellij Terminal but it does not recognize the command. In Command Prompt and Windows power shell the command in recognized (I added the git path in System Environment Variables). I am also aware that Intellij has an GUI integration with Git.

So, can anyone tell me how can I use the git command in the Intellij terminal.

Comment: I'm not windows user, but I think, you could get some usefull info from [this post](https://codeaweso.me/2013/12/cygwin-terminal-with-intellij-idea-13/) You can try setup path to bashshell, or install cygwin, and setup git there. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201881/1601606) may be helpfull.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

**Setup JetBrains(InteliJ, WebStorm, PHPStorm) IDE terminal to use GIT bash**

- File
- Settings
- (Enter 'Terminal' in search)
- Change Shell path to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```

If you have another directory for installed git change it respectively.

Comment: Is there a way to specify Mintty somehow? Doing it this way does not allow me to do a few things, like be able to print the unicode char `\u03BB`

Comment: I'm not shure, but i think JetBrains plugin "Command Line Tool Support" will be usefull for purposes like that.

Comment: Dont forget the to put Quotes for directory. Intellij had issues launching terminal

Comment: Or to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

Comment: This does no longer work with Win10 and PHPStorm 2018.2.6
The bash window just pops up outside the IDE and closes imediately again.

Comment: Following the thread here helped me to fix it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207627665-Can-t-start-the-git-bash-in-the-terminal-Tools-Terminal-
I guess changing form to float, windowed and back to docked fixed it

Comment: On Windows 10 I was running into an odd error at first when specifying "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i, the error went away after I created a .bashrc file. Once I created the file (no content in the file) the terminal opened and gave a message that it created a .bash_profile file. I saved the file  to this location  C:\Users\userName\.bashrc

Comment: Don't forget to **restart** Intellij

Comment: This anwer can't be correct - "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i" is by no means a path. And yes, it does not work with PyCharm 2019.3 / Windows 10 / git-scm 2.25

Comment: If you're using Git For Windows, make sure **not** to use _C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe_, but _C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe_ - otherwise the command prompt will open in a separate window!

Comment: Open a new terminal after to make sure the changes are applied.

'Crtl + Shift - T' for IntelliJ Idea

Comment: If you get broken-looking output (`[0;39;1m`) from Gradle, [setting `TERM=cygwin`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13279#issuecomment-772957621) should solve that for now.

Answer (score 6):

For me, it works also but only the path of Git Bash has changed in Windows :

```
"C:\Users\REPLACE_THIS_BY_YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Comment: Worked fine for my setup: Windows 10, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Ultimate Edition), both paths `"C:\Users\my-user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` and `"C:\Users\my-user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` worked.

Answer (score 4):

In the IDEA settings make sure that your terminal path leads to "usr/bin" instead of "/bin".

[image: IDEA terminal settings tab]

As a result you will see pretty rich console output:

[image: Result console output]

Answer (score 2):

The full path is not needed anymore (windows), I just replaced `cmd.exe` to `sh.exe` and bingo was his name O

Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path > `sh.exe`

Comment: It's not needed any longer because of some magic inside IntelliJ? Nonsense. If "sh.exe" is in your PATH then of course it will find by PATH lookup ..

Comment: I would improve this answer putting bash.exe

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the Git Bash through IntelliJ had TERM=xterm-256color.
Regular Git Bash had TERM=xterm

To fix the garbled characters issue in IntelliJ Idea,
Go to `"File | Settings | Tools | Terminal"`

```
Environment Variables:  TERM=cygwin
```

In IntelliJ Terminal, Shell Path I was using was already:

> `C:\Users\<userId>\programs\Git\bin\bash.exe --login -i`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinstall anything. Go to:

- File
- Settings
- Search for terminal
- in shell path type: `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` (or another directory where you installed Git)

Comment: I have struggled looking for changing the bash in terminal for switching sdkman java .This solution worked for me

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

IntelliJ:
    File->Settings->Version Control->Git:

On the right side, Path to Git executable:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"`

Comment: Question wants git bash, not in-built git feature

Comment: It gave me what I wanted when google lead me here!