# A plugin to open a terminal in a particular directory selected from the project tree

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use `git bash` for my terminal configuration and it has `--cd` option where I can pass the path to open terminal in:

[image]

I have pretty deeply nested directory structure and thought it would be very convenient to open terminal in the directory I select in the tree:

[image]

Is there a plugin that can do that? If not, how hard will it be to write my own simple plugin?

It will probably be very basic:

- read the currently selected folder path
- run "open terminal" action supplied the command line string with the concatenated path

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup git in Intellij terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676150/setup-git-in-intellij-terminal)

Comment: @Meo, how is it duplicate?

Comment: You may drag a folder (from Project View) and drop it into the tabs area in already opened built-in Terminal -- will it work for you?

Comment: @LazyOne, that's absolutely great! Thanks. Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

there are no such plugins, please vote for [IDEA-116724](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116724) and linked tickets.

You can try opening sh as External tool instead, like:

```
Program: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Parameters: /C "start sh.exe"
Working directory: $FileDir$
```

[image]
the only issue is that it will be opened as external window, not inside IDE

Comment: in `Settings | Tools | External Tools`, press `+` to add a new tool

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm